# For beginners, what are the advantages and disadvantages of using a training line along with a slack-line?

Tags: gear, slacklining

I know a training line + slackline would cost more than a slack-line itself, but I'm wondering if I didn't buy a slackline+training line I'd have to step on and fall off before I'm able to balance on it without anything to hold onto. But I also doubt the strength of a training line. I wonder whether it would just break if I grabbed onto it while learning how to slackline. Is there anyway the supposed benefits of using a training line don't exist as the marketing people would suggest otherwise?

Comment: I don't know much about slackline, so I could be totally wrong, but I'd guess the training line purpose is to give you another assistance to balance. Not actually hold your whole body weight, but give you the chance of using your hands to improve the balance. Like when you touch a wall while standing in one foot: you don't actually put much force on the wall, but it's enough to help you keep balanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of the training line is three fold:

1. It puts your arms in the correct position. This helps you use better form.
2. It gives you the ability to "push off" the line with your arms, allowing you to balance more easily. You are not putting all your body weight onto the training line. @IanC in the comments nailed it!
3. Faster "results". You can "slackline" sooner

Without the training line you will be stepping on and off a lot more as you learn to get your balance. When learning to slackline you don't immediately start walking. The first step is just getting stationary balance. It takes patience while learning. The training line allows you to get more instant gratification of success. Whether or not it actually speeds up the process of learning to slackline (without a training line) I think is hard to say.

I personally learned without one, as did all my friends. I'm not sure it is super necessary. If you will be setting up the line for a lot of younger kids then it might be nice for younger kids while they are learning to be more successful. At climbing gyms without training lines you will often see parents acting like a training line for younger kids by holding out their hand for the kid to gently push off of.